# Fastest way to run column operations in Spark

Tags: r, apache-spark, pyspark, sparkr

I want to extract some statistical measurements from large Spark DataFrames (approx. 250K records, 250 columns) as e.g. max, mean, stddev, etc., yet I also want some non-standard measurements as e.g. skewness.
I am working on databricks using SparkR API. I know that there is the possibility of getting basic statistics via summary

```
  df <- SparkR::asDataFrame(mtcars)
  SparkR::summary(df, "min", "max", "50%", "mean") -> mySummary
  head(mySummary)
```

However, this does not cover other measures as skewness and I am bassically extracting them using

```
 SparkR::select(df, SparkR::skewness(df$mpg)) -> mpg_Skewness
 head(mpg_Skewness)
```

This works, yet I am looking for a more performant way doing so. No matter whether I am looping over columns or using an apply function over the columns, Spark is always executing one job per column which are run subsequently.

I also tried to execute this for all columns as one job, but this is even slower.

Is it possible to force Spark to execute these kind of calculations separately for all columns but in parallel? What else could you propose to do such column operations as performant as possible? Any hints are highly appreciated!